# how to get html text differences like svn?

Tags: php, html, diff

I am using PEAR text_diff class to get comparison of text. It works correct for plain text, but when I try to compare text with HTML tags, It gives wrong result

is there any way to compare two HTML blocks and in result display text that pre-serv its HTML and show differences like svn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, these two are fantastic:

- https://github.com/cygri/htmldiff (Python)
- http://www.w3.org/People/Bos/#jpegxmp (C, must be compiled)

Yes, none of the programs are written in plain PHP. You just run them via PHP:

```
// Python script:
$html_diff = shell_exec ('python /path/to/htmldiff version1.html version2.html');
// C program:
$html_diff = shell_exec ('/path/to/htmldiff --start-delete="<span class=\'delete\'>" --end-delete="</span>" --start-insert="<span class=\'insert\'>" --end-insert="</span>" version1.html version2.html');
```

Since they aren't written in PHP, you can enjoy the incredible high speed :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which OS you're on, but I always use Meld on Ubuntu for diff:ing non-versioned files. It doesn't have any problems diffing HTML code (or anything else afaik):

http://meldmerge.org/

Comment: thanks for your reply, But I want text differences using PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this right in javascript itself. Check out [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).

Diff demo [here](http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html).

Comment: That is not a HTML diff tool.